# Getting non HTTP traffic to OpenShift Origin (Ingress IP/External IP)?

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

I'm still trying to wrap my head around how Ingress/External IPs work within OpenShift, and am hoping for some community advice on how to solve this issue.

Currently the way "we" operate is that traffic hits an external IP, gets NAT'd to a VIP on our load balancer, which load balances a pool of backend servers that either service HTTP or some other type of traffic. We don't look at host headers to determine where to land traffic like the OpenShift router does, that type of traffic handling doesn't work for us. We have a direct mapping of 1 external IP to 1 internal service.

We're looking at moving to OpenShift, but would like to preserve this type of 1 to 1 mapping of external IP to VIP (internal service). We are also going to be standing up an OpenShift cluster per customer we have -- meaning each customer has their own IP space on our network.

Ideally we'd just be able to re-use the same internal IP space that our nodes live on. Say we have our nodes on 10.10.20.0/24, nodes being 10.10.20.10 - 10.10.20.30, we could use higher IPs (10.10.20.31+) for our service VIPs with Keepalived advertising the service IPs so we can get traffic to them. But I don't believe this is how OpenShift works.

**Is the only way to get outside traffic into a cluster to actually route a full subnet to an OpenShift node?** This seems like a massive single point of failure, so I'm thinking I'm understanding something incorrect about how Ingress IPs work.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about this. It's my first post here.

Normally you should use Service Type: Loadbalacer in combo w/ keepalived.

This blog post provides a startup to setup external services.
https://me2digital.online/2017/01/12/openshift-ingress-setup/

It looks a little overkill to create for every service a keepalived instance. You are also limited to 255 IPs due vrrp_router_id limitation.

On the other side, you can just create on keepalived instance with 255 vrrp instances.

External Traffic is still routed via one node but its not pinned to one node. See https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.5/admin_guide/high_availability.html#cluster-ha-ingressIP for more informations.